# xslt doc-available test throwing fatal java.io.FileNotFoundException instead of gracefully going to otherwise

Tags: xslt, saxon

When running the code below i get the following error:

`FODC0002  I/O error reported by XML parser processing Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException:`

Here's the conditional I'm running

```
           <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="document(concat($repo-path, $wit-slug, '_', $itemid, '.xml'))">
                <transcriptions>
                  <transcription transcriptionDefault="true">
                    <type>diplomatic</type>
                    <version versionDefault="true">
                      <hash>transcription</hash>
                      <versionNo n="dev">head-dev</versionNo>
                      <url><xsl:value-of select="concat($wit-slug, '_', $itemid , '.xml')"/></url>
                    </version>
                  </transcription>
                </transcriptions>
              </xsl:when>
```

The conditional exists precisely to avoid this error. Sometimes the file is there sometimes it is not. When it is not, then produce the following output, otherwise just move on.

Running this in Oxygen I notice that I do get these errors, but they are not fatal. The script continues to finish.

In the past running saxon in the command line resulted in the same behaviour.

Now, something seems to have changed underneath my feet, such that the saxon command line tool is completely stopping when it hits this error instead of continuing on.

Here's the java version on my mac

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

I'd be very grateful for any thoughts or advice.

Comment: It looks to me as if you could use `test="doc-available(concat($repo-path, $wit-slug, '_', $itemid, '.xml'))"` instead of `test="document(concat($repo-path, $wit-slug, '_', $itemid, '.xml'))"`, no?

Comment: Hmm, you title talks about `doc-available` but the code shown uses `document` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recently changed the version of Saxon?

[Undocumented change of IO failure handling when using document() between Saxon 9 and 10](https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4752)

Comment: I definitely bet that is it. Frustrating.

Comment: $ brew saxon info = `saxon: stable 10.3`

Comment: Fixed in Saxon 10.5.